# whatsapp chat export and convert

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-mining, data-extraction

Looking to convert ALL whatsapp group chats with media  to csv file
without character limit.i know option is their to export chat but with limited characters and print doesn't work either.
Is their any way using python if we can extract all data ***with MEDIA*** from backup or android phone

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [WhatsAPP FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/chats/how-to-save-your-chat-history/?lang=en):

> When exporting with media, you can send up to 10,000 latest messages. Without media, you can send 40,000 messages. These constraints are due to maximum email sizes.

So no, there is no way. This limit isnt set for iOS users. I had the same struggle when building a [tool](https://github.com/SpiritFour/whatsanalyze) to analyze my WhatsApp chats. The only thing you can do is to backup the messages under android and maybe access the backup somehow.